# service and node parameter in getaddinfo()

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I was checking `int getaddrinfo(const char *node, const char *service,
                const struct addrinfo *hints,
                struct addrinfo **res)` on linux man page, where it says I can only set`Either node or service, but not both, may be NULL`. I don't quite understand, why I can't set both the node and service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My manpage for `getaddrinfo` includes the quote, but it does not mean what you think. It says:

> Either node or service, but not both, may be NULL.

IE you can specify both, or specify one. However, you cannot specify neither; having both as NULL is not permitted, everything else is.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading the Linux manpage for getaddrinfo() it says:

> Either node or service, but not both, may be NULL.

So `node` or  `service` *can* be NULL.

But you can very much set both of them.

What you cannot do, is set both the `node` and `service` to NULL. Either one of them, or both of them
have to be set to a valid c string.